# Displaying data from different tables and displaying them In details with summary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am very beginner and I am just learning by myself, so please excuse if I can't even express what I want to say in Programmer way!
I am trying to develop simple business application that can do this:

> 1. Register Employee or Customer.
> 2. Can store expenses or money that employee can take in advance before salary payment (This can be done several times, or it may be
>      zero)
> 3. Can store payments (Salary given to the employee) - It can be also done several times
> 4. It can calculate all expenses, calculate all payments, then find their difference, hence will be paid the remaining of the balance!

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(    CustomerID INT IDENTITY (1000,1)
    ,FirstName VARCHAR(40)
    ,RegDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
    ,Phone VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE Expense
(    ExpenseID INT IDENTITY (1000,1)
    ,CustomerID INT NOT NULL
    ,ExpDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
    ,Amount MONEY
    ,Comment VARCHAR (100)
);

CREATE TABLE TblLoad
(    LoadID INT IDENTITY (1000,1) --PRIMARY KEY 
    ,CustomerID INT NOT NULL
    ,DepDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
    ,Amount MONEY
    ,FromTo VARCHAR (100)
);




select Customer.CustomerID, Customer.FirstName, Expense.Amount As ExpenseAmount from Customer inner join 
Expense on Customer.CustomerID = Expense.CustomerID
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = 1000

select Customer.CustomerID, Customer.FirstName, TblLoad.Amount As LoadAmount from Customer inner join 
TblLoad on Customer.CustomerID = TblLoad.CustomerID
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = 1000

SELECT Customer.CustomerID, Customer.FirstName, e.SE as AmountExp , l.SL as AmountLoad , (l.SL - e.SE) as FinalPay
FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN (SELECT CustomerID, SUM(Amount) AS SE FROM Expense GROUP BY CustomerID) E
ON Customer.CustomerID = e.CustomerID
INNER JOIN (SELECT CustomerID, SUM(Amount) AS SL FROM TblLoad GROUP BY CustomerID) L
ON Customer.CustomerID = l.CustomerID
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = 1000
```

Attached are pictures of what I expected, and what I was willing 
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjtVa.jpg)

[Result From The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZG8w.png)

Comment: Question is not clear what you want query help or bd model  what is from to means use dr ot  cr  ..

Comment: If you can see the attached picture of what I was expecting, please ignore everything else and just use that picture and show me the solution. Thank you

Comment: i am not clear how you are splitting by customer id in your final output , the  month in your expense and payment table are different should the be the same? or is there some other matching process?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly congrats on getting as far as you have. The bad news is that t-sql is not a reporting tool - you need to look elsewhere if you want pretty output (SSRS,Crystal reports, excel etc,etc) to get anywhere near to your required ouput in t-sql you need to get a bit creative for example:-

```
/*
drop table customer
drop table expense
drop table TblLoad
CREATE TABLE Customer
(    CustomerID INT --IDENTITY (1000,1)
    ,FirstName VARCHAR(40)
    ,RegDate DATETIME --DEFAULT GETDATE()
    ,Phone VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
(    CustomerID 
    ,FirstName 
    ,RegDate 
    ,Phone ) 
VALUES
(1001,'Emp1',cast('2015/10/20 00:00:00.000' as datetime), null),
(1002,'Emp2',cast('2015/10/22 00:00:00.000' as datetime), null),
(1003,'Emp3',cast('2015/10/25 00:00:00.000' as datetime), null)

CREATE TABLE Expense
(    ExpenseID INT --IDENTITY (1000,1)
    ,CustomerID INT NOT NULL
    ,ExpDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
    ,Amount MONEY
    ,Comment VARCHAR (100)
);
truncate table expense
insert into expense
(    ExpenseID 
    ,CustomerID 
    ,ExpDate 
    ,Amount 
    --,Comment 
)
Values
(1001,1001,cast('2015/10/21' as datetime),100),
(1002,1001,cast('2015/11/22' as datetime),20),
(1003,1001,cast('2015/12/25' as datetime),80),
(1004,1002,cast('2015/11/21' as datetime),100),
(1005,1002,cast('2015/12/25' as datetime),200),
(1006,1003,cast('2015/11/25' as datetime),300)

CREATE TABLE TblLoad
(    LoadID INT --IDENTITY (1000,1) --PRIMARY KEY 
    ,CustomerID INT NOT NULL
    ,DepDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
    ,Amount MONEY
    ,FromTo VARCHAR (100)
);
truncate table tblload
insert into tblload
(    loadID 
    ,CustomerID 
    ,depDate 
    ,Amount 
    --,Comment 
)
Values
(1001,1001,cast('2015/10/21' as datetime),1000),
(1002,1001,cast('2015/11/21' as datetime),200),
(1003,1001,cast('2015/12/24' as datetime),800),
(1004,1002,cast('2015/11/21' as datetime),2000),
(1005,1002,cast('2015/12/25' as datetime),500),
(1006,1003,cast('2015/11/24' as datetime),4000)
*/
select      
            --case
            --when right(rtrim(cast(yyyymm as char(8))) ,2 ) = '13' then char(30)
            --else cast(yyyymm as char(8))
            --end
            case
            when right(rtrim(cast(yyyymm as char(8))) ,2 ) = '13' then char(30)
            else cast(customerid as char(4))
            end
            ,case
            when right(rtrim(cast(yyyymm as char(8))) ,2 ) = '13' then 'Total'
            else firstname
            end
            ,sum(amountexp) amuntexp
            ,sum(amountload) amountload
            ,sum(amountload) - sum(amountexp) finalpay

from
(

select      year(e.expdate) * 100 + month(e.expdate) yyyymm,
            C.CustomerID, c.FirstName, sum(e.amount) as AmountExp , 0 as AmountLoad , 0 as FinalPay
FROM        Customer c
INNER JOIN  Expense  E ON C.CustomerID = e.CustomerID
group   by  year(e.expdate) , month(e.expdate),
            C.CustomerID, c.FirstName
union
select      year(e.expdate) * 100 +  13 ,
            C.CustomerID, c.FirstName, sum(e.amount) as AmountExp , 0 as AmountLoad , 0 as FinalPay
FROM        Customer c
INNER JOIN  Expense  E ON C.CustomerID = e.CustomerID
group   by  year(e.expdate) * 100 +  13,
            C.CustomerID, c.FirstName
union
select      year(l.depdate) * 100 +  month(l.depdate) yyyymm,
            C.CustomerID, c.FirstName, 0 asAmountExp , sum(l.amount) as AmountLoad , 0 as FinalPay
FROM        Customer c
INNER JOIN  tblload  l ON C.CustomerID = l.CustomerID
group   by  year(l.depdate) , month(l.depdate),
            C.CustomerID, c.FirstName
union
select      year(l.depdate) * 100 +  13 yyyymm,
            C.CustomerID, c.FirstName, 0 asAmountExp , sum(l.amount) as AmountLoad , 0 as FinalPay
FROM        Customer c
INNER JOIN  tblload  l ON C.CustomerID = l.CustomerID
group   by  year(l.depdate) * 100 +  13,
            C.CustomerID, c.FirstName
) s
group   by  s.CustomerID,s.firstname,yyyymm 
order   by  s.CustomerID,s.firstname,yyyymm
```